# Errors trying to import an external QML module to my project

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to import the modules from [papyros](http://papyros.io/developer/index.html) to my application.
For that I cloned the repo, and then I added the modules path to the **QML2_IMPORT_PATH** env var.

The papyros is already with the qmldir files set correctly, so all I'd to do is to add the dirs to the QML2_IMPORT_PATH

i.e: If the qmldir is inside **/myhome/qml-material/modules/Material** dir, then I added the **/myhome/qml-material/modules/Material** to the QML2_IMPORT_PATH var.

I also tried to add using:

```
engine.addImportPath("/myhome/qml-material/modules/Material");
```

in the main.cpp just before load the main qml file.

Nothing seems to be working, I can't import the components inside my app and the Qt Creator code completion completely ignore the new dirs.
I tried to add in several different ways:

```
import modules.Material.Action 0.1
import Material.Action 0.1
import Action 0.1
```

But I keep receiving the error:
**module "Module name" is not installed**

The only way it works is using the full path:

```
import "/myhome/qml-material/modules/Material/Action.qml" as Action
```

But, of course, it's not what I want to.

Any idea how can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should do `engine.addImportPath("/myhome/qml-material/modules/");`
not `engine.addImportPath("/myhome/qml-material/modules/Material");`
cause when you write `import Material 0.1`, Qt will search to a folder named Material, if you are already in it, this will not work.

Comment: Thanks, I added to QML2_IMPORT_PATH instead following your recommendation, now it's working despite Qt Creator still couldn't autocomplete the components.